# object returned empty description sharkorm

Tags: ios, objective-c, dbaccess

Why when I commit an object and I do an `NSLog(@"model: %@", self)` in `entityDidInsert` in the console it only prints "model:"
and when I do a `po self` on debugging mode I get the message "object returned empty description".

The object is stored correctly.

Comment: That is odd, but it has come up before.  I will search through my emails to see what the resolution was.

Comment: Thank you @Adrian_H when you find the solution let me know please

Comment: I have been unable to find anything written down, but if you can create an application that demonstrates it, or test against the new version due in a couple of days then we should be able to get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 0):

Check optimalization level in 'Build Settings'.

Try set it to None [-O0], then 'Strip debug symbols during copy' to 'NO'

Optional - clear Delivery data

Comment: I already have Optimization level set to None [-O0] and Strip debug symbols during copy set to NO